# An example is/would be

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

Which of the following two sentences is correct, and why?

> A good example of that phenomenon would be....
>
> A good example of that phenomenon is....

What exactly are the differences between these two constructions (in a science setting)? To give my two cents, "would be" sounds more natural. However, I do find it logically incoherent, as you are giving what you believe a good example is, and using 'would be' would denotes a hypothetical situation (modal verb), making the sentence sound like "It would be a good example if it weren't for the fact that..."

Please provide your understanding in addition to the sentence you believe is correct.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: In a fact based context, I would use "is". Using "would" reads like the phenomenon is a suggestion rather than a fact.

Comment: As you suggest yourself, *would be* generally works better with a hypothetical example and *is* with an actual example. As in: *A good example of that phenomenon is the melting of the Arctic ice cap*, and *A good example of that phenomenon would be a tsunami caused by an under-sea earthquake*. There are also cases where either construction would work: *A good example of that phenomenon would be/is the elephant mother's protective behaviour".

Comment: From what I picked up reading your comments, is it fair to say that a hypothetical example is one that you thought up but doesn't necessarily happen in real life? As in, a good example of self-defense would be USA striking down missiles from Russia.